# Flash AS3 Creating components on stage via Button

Tags: actionscript-3

Sorry for my complicated questioning ;)

I've created several components on my stage (Slider, TextLabel, CheckBox, ...) with the addChild(...) method. Now, if the user needs one Slider component more (for another input), I want to give him a button "addButton" (already on stage) with an CLICK addEventListener. The function which is fired in the addEventListener should create a new Slider component on stage, e.g.

```
addButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,addSlider("slid1",20,160,250,0,250,30));
```

The problem is to pass the parameters to the function, i need to set the new Slider to several basic values, like position, width, minimum, maximum and so on....

Can this be achieved in this way?
thx,
edwin

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this. The simplest way is to call your function inside a mouse event handler:

```
addButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addSliderHandler);

function addSliderHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
{
    addSlider("slid1",20,160,250,0,250,30);
}
```

EDIT (to answer your comment question):

To position your new component according to existing components, you can keep a variable reference to the position in the script and pass this as a parameter. For instance, suppose you want the first generated slider to be at y:160, and every slider to be 40px more than this, change the script to this:

```
var sliderY:int = 160;

addButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addSliderHandler);

function addSliderHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
{
    addSlider("slid1",20,sliderY,250,0,250,30);//Pass sliderY instead of literal number
    sliderY += 40;//Add 40 to sliderY
}
```

Now, every time you use this function to create a button it will be positioned at y = sliderY, then it will add 40 to sliderY....so the first one generated will be at 160, the next at 200, the next at 240 etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mick for your answer, this works fine!

Now, another problem occurs. I want to set the parameters according to what sliders already exist on stage. Say, the third parameter (160) should be the y-position of the new slider. So now I have to know the y-position of the "latest" added slider and pass this value +40px to the next slider. I hope you know what I mean?

thx,
edwin

Comment: The answer actually showed how to do this with the X parameter, but I have edited it to work for the Y position. Have a look, let me know how you get on with it...if it works, please accept answer, thanks.